# Android OpenGL blending similar to iPhone

Tags: android, opengl-es, buffer

I was wondering if Android has anything similar to iPhone's kEAGLDrawablePropertyRetainedBacking property.  I'm interested in not calling glClear every frame and having the buffer basically remember the previous buffer's state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create your EGLConfig, use the bit EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED_BIT. Then you can use eglSurfaceAttrib to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR to EGL_BUFFER_PRESERVED. This will preserve the content of the buffer between two draws.

Comment: I searched around for the EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED_BIT and it seems it is first mentioned in the EGL 1.4 Spec [link](http://www.khronos.org/registry/egl/specs/eglspec.1.4.20101006.pdf).  The Android SDK shows interfaces for EGL10 and EGL11.I think I might be out of luck for now.  Thanks for describing how this is possible.  Hopefully I can implement it in the future!

Comment: I used it myself to implement Android 3.0's hardware accelerated 2D pipeline. To use it I simply copied the values of the constants I needed. This of course will work only with devices that support this feature so you need to check whether the device supports it.

Comment: Thanks!  I'll look into more closely.